# Generic that creates interface with overwritten properties

Tags: typescript

Given a `Person` type

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: {
    line1: string,
    line2: string | null | number,
    zip: string | number,
  },
};
```

I'd like to apply overwrites and modify this interface.

```
type PersonOverwrites = {
  address: {
    line2?: string,
    zip: string,
  },
};
```

From these two interfaces I would like to create this:

```
type PersonModified = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: {
    line1: string,
    line2?: string,
    zip: string,
  },
}
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
type PersonModified = Overwrite<Person, PersonOverwrites>
```

How can I create this type of Generic?

**Update**

This should complain:

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U;


type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: {
    line1: string,
    line2: string | null | number,
    zip: string | number,
    address?: {
        line1: string,
        line2: string | null | number,
        zip: string | number,
        address?: {
            line1: string,
            line2: string | null | number,
            zip: string | number,
        },
    },
  },
};

type PersonOverwrites = {
    address: {
        line2?: string,
        zip: string,
        address?: {
            address: {
                pizzaDelivery: boolean,
            },
        },
    },
};

const person: Person = {
    name: 'Thomas',
    age: 12,
    address: {
        line1: 'hi',
        line2: 'hi',
        zip: 'hi',
        address: {
            line1: 'hi',
            line2: 'hi',
            zip: 'hi',
            address: {
                line1: 'hi',
                line2: 'hi',
                zip: 'hi',
                // pizzaDelivery: true,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how deeply nested you want this to be, but you might want something like this:

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U;

type PersonModified = DeepMerge<Person, PersonOverwrites>
```

The idea is that `DeepMerge<T, U>` either evaluates to just `U` if either `T` or `U` is not an object type, or it walks through each combined key of `T` or `U` and merges more deeply.  The specifics around how it determines which properties should be optional, and how it decides when to stop merging are straightforward but tedious to explain.  If you need something specific elaborated, let me know.

You can verify that `PersonModified` is equivalent to

```
type PersonModified = {
    address: {
        line2?: string | undefined;
        zip: string;
        line1: string;
    };
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

as you wanted.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: How do we make this support `n` depth?

Comment: That should support arbitrary depth.

Comment: I would expect if you switched an optional deep prop to not optional it would require all existing properties as well as new ones from the overwrites. Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Building of @jcalz answer I believe this fixes the optional issue.

```
type Merge<M, N> = Omit<M, Extract<keyof M, keyof N>> & N;

type DeepMerge<T, U> = [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (Merge<T, U>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : Merge<T, U>;
```